# Symfony2 MySQL: INSERT SELECT syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having problems with writing correct MySql query. I want to insert new collection for every user with id higher than 1000 but less than 10000.

```
$conn = $this->em->getConnection();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO collection (name, type) 
                   values(:name, :type) 
                   SELECT  * FROM user WHERE id<:endUser AND id>:startUser');
$stmt->bindValue('name', 'Default');
$stmt->bindValue('type', 0);
$stmt->bindValue('startUser', 1000);
$stmt->bindValue('endUser', 10000);
$stmt->execute();
```

This what I tried to write, but I get syntax error. Please explain me how to correct query

**UPD**

I should have given detailed structure of tables.

*Collection*

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collection` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
         `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
         `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `IDX_FC4D6532A76ED395` (`user_id`)
          );
```

*User*

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
         `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
          );
```

User has one-to-many relationship with Collection.

Comment: show us exact error message

Comment: Read a manual for `INSERT INTO SELECT` query

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski The error is:  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax  
   to use near 'SELECT  *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a SELECT INTO you have to select the values you want to place in the new row **and only those values**. And you dont use the VALUES() clause.

As you are using static values for the new rows and not values from the `user` table you can do it like this.

**Oh and I see in your edit you were using the wrong table name** It should have been `fos_user`

Also as fos_user.user_id is a  `NOT NULL` field you need to include that column in the list of fields in the insert.

```
$conn = $this->em->getConnection();

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO collection (user_id, name, type) 
                              SELECT id, 'default', 0
                              FROM fos_user
                              WHERE id > :startUser AND id < :endUser');

$stmt->bindValue('startUser', 1000);
$stmt->bindValue('endUser', 10000);
$stmt->execute();
```